# Convert the_geom to text and then transform

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I have this query that returns the_geom as text. However how could I also apply a transform to the same query. I can do this separately with the second example. Though I would like to do this to all the rows in my table, and in that example I copied the st_astext output into the transform query.

**`select  sitename,  st_astext(the_geom) from sites_tbl;`**

sitename   |                st_astext

Belfast A    | POINT(145592 530021)

**`ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID('POINT(145592 530021)'::geometry,27700), 4326));`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ST_Transform in your first query too.

```
select sitename, st_astext( ST_Transform( the_geom, 4326 ) ) from sites_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a query I use to write out the LAT/LON of points from data stored in State Plane (feet):

```
select 
residential_block_points.geoid_num
, st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(residential_block_points.geom, 4326))) as X
, st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(residential_block_points.geom, 4326))) as Y
from 
residential_block_points
```

and you could add this data as new fields in the existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE "residential_block_points" ADD x double precision;
ALTER TABLE "residential_block_points" ADD y double precision;
UPDATE "residential_block_points" SET x = st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(residential_block_points.geom, 4326)));
UPDATE "residential_block_points" SET y = st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(residential_block_points.geom, 4326)));
```